# Detect GPS automaticlly

Tags: android

how can I detect automaticlly that a mobile is equipped by a GPS system or no? I found tetsts that give if a GPS is closed or now but what I search is about detecting if GPS system exists or no

Comment: Are you trying to avoid installation on devices without GPS? Or is this just a check you'd like to do at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

Do this way

```
PackageManager pmanager = getPackageManager();
boolean hasGps = pmanager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS);

if(hasGps){
  // gps is available
}else{
  // gps is not available
}
```

Comment: I think I actually prefer this!

Answer (score 1):

Call `LocationManager.getAllProviders()` and check whether `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` is in the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only install on devices with GPS, then you have options in your manifest, which the Play store implements.

Check the Android Developer section on `uses-feature` here:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

This is the code you would put into your manifest.

```
<uses-feature
  android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
  android:required="true" />
```

The Play store would only make this app available to devices that have GPS.

Note that the Android system itself does nothing with this information, it is only for the Play store.

However, if you want a **runtime check**, then I recommend [@Biraj's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23152411/383414) or [@OrhanC1's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23152358/383414). They should both accomplish what you need, in slightly different ways.

Answer (score -2):

Try this code :

```
 // getting GPS status
       LocationManager  locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Hope this helps

Try this code to find whether GPS exists :

```
           PackageManager pm= this.getPackageManager();
           boolean hasGps =pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS);
```

Comment: this returns if the GPS is active, turned on. It doesn't help to decide if GPS exists on the device, but is turned off.